# How to correct the selector in Apify to get data from JSON data link?

Tags: jquery, json, css-selectors, apify

I am using Apify to get data from json file links. Here is the json data:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <pre>
            {"exhibitor-single":[{"firstname":"Ines","lastname":"Konwiarz","email":"georg.jansen@020epos.de"}]}
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, I used following code in apify webscraper task.

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const request = context.request;
    const $ = context.jQuery;

   var data =  $('body > pre').html();
   var items = JSON.parse(data);

       return {
        Url: request.url,
        Last_Name: items[`exhibitor-single`].lastname,
        First_Name: items[`exhibitor-single`].firstname,
        Email: items[`exhibitor-single`].email

        };
}
```

The variable **`data`** have the correct css selector for the json data. But, its not returning any data. Can anyone help me find what went wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The `data` variable would contain the HTML Content of `pre` element directly under `body` element. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have edited the details, and if you want i can share the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pageFunction structure, I guess that you are using [apify/web-scraper](https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper).

If you want to get just data from JSON links you can easily use [apify/cheerio-scraper](https://apify.com/apify/cheerio-scraper). It will cost much less compute power as you don't need open whole browser.

You need to use set up pageFunction in cheerio scraper to get JSON data:
pageFunction:

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { request ,json } = context;
    const items =  json;
    return {
        Url: request.url,
        Last_Name: items.lastname,
        First_Name: items[`exhibitor-single`].firstname,
        Email: items.email
    };
}
```

Cheerio scraper supports only HTML response by default, you need to update Additional mime types in Advanced configurations with value:

```
[
  "application/json"
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, It didnt return any data either.

Comment: I tested it on my JSON response and it works. Can you provide your JSON URL and I will test it there?